# Which preposition follows "in the week" when denoting a specific week of the year?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I'm pretty sure that the correct preposition is *of*:

> I'll probably start working on this issue in the week of June, 8th.

However, there are thousands of hits on Google using the preposition *from*.

I guess there are many usages of non-natives among those; but it also appears to me that people tend to use *from* when talking about a period of time:

> I'll probably work on this issue in the week *from* 8th through 12th of June.

This tendency is probably based on the fact that it is "from ... to/through ...":

> I'll be working on this issue from 8th to 12th of June.

Question: Is "in the week from" correct/acceptable if a period of time follows? Are there perhaps differences between American, British, and other dialects of English?
Or is it plainly wrong to add the preposition *from* to the prepositional phrase *in the week*, disregarding what follows next?

Comment: " ... in the week starting ..."

Answer (score 2):

"The week of March 16" is correct and in common usage.

"The week from March 16," with no further date range language, is incorrect.

"The week from March 16 through March 22" and "The week from March 16 until March 22" are both grammatically correct, but redundant and not common as stock usages.

Note that it's not typical to use "in" before "the week of." You just say "I'm going home the week of March 16" not "I'll be away the week of March 16," assuming you are referring to the week as a whole. If you want to refer to a specific moment within the week, you would more typically use "during," e.g. "I will do it during the week of March 16."

Answer (score 1):

"the week of *date*" means the week (starting from either Sunday or Monday) during which that date occurs, often but not necessarily starting from that date.

For example "I will be absent the week of August 9th" could refer to the week beginning Monday August 7th.

"the week from *date*" specifically means the week that begins on that date.